# Flutter TextStyle / fontSize

Tags: flutter, textstyle

I would like the TextStyle / fontSize to simplify my app.

for this it would be necessary to make the line "

> fontSize: Get.width * .030,

" of the attached code available, similar to the color "

> {Color color = Colors.white}

This is the code I want to customize ...

```
TextStyle _textStyle({Color color = Colors.white}) {
  return GoogleFonts.getFont(
    'Unica One',
    fontSize: Get.width * .030,
    color: color,
    letterSpacing: 0.5,
  );
}
```

And it should look something like that, but unfortunately I don't know exactly how to put it together correctly

```
TextStyle _textStyle({Color color = Colors.white}{FontSize fontSize = Get.width * .030}) {
  return GoogleFonts.getFont(
    'Unica One',
    fontSize: fontSize,
    color: color,
    letterSpacing: 0.5,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text class with style,

```
class StoryText extends Text {
  StoryText(String title, {Color mColor, double mFontSize})
      : super(title,
            style: GoogleFonts.getFont(
              'Unica One',
              fontSize: mFontSize,
              color: mColor,
              letterSpacing: 0.5,
            ));
}

// Use of above class
StoryText('title', mColor: Colors.red, mFontSize: Get.width * .030,),
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to change **FontSize** type to **double**.

````
TextStyle _textStyle({Color color = Colors.white ,double fontSize = Get.width * .030}) {
  return GoogleFonts.getFont(
    'Unica One',
    fontSize: fontSize,
    color: color,
    letterSpacing: 0.5,
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Can you maybe tell me how I use this in the "hintText:" of a "TextField ("?

when I do it like this

```
hintStyle: StyledText (
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
```

then I get the error

> "The argument type 'StyledText' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'TextStyle?'. (Documentation)"

I have adapted your code so that it works so far, thank you again for that  .. would only like to use it with the "hintStyle"

```
import 'package: flutter / cupertino.dart';
import 'package: flutter / material.dart';
import 'package: google_fonts / google_fonts.dart';

class StyledText extends Text {
  StyledText (
      String title,
      {
        double fontSize = 10.5,
        color = Colors.white,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.w100,
        letterSpacing = 0.5,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      })
      : super (title,
      style: GoogleFonts.getFont (
        'Unica One',
        fontSize: fontSize,
        color: color,
        fontWeight: fontWeight,
        letterSpacing: 0.5,
      ),
    textAlign: textAlign,
  );
}
```